# Estilos CSS al Arrastrar Un Archivo

Tags: css, html5, typescript, ionic

realice una pequeña pagina en Ionic 4 donde me permite arrastrar archivos, cuando detecto el evento 'drag' cambio la clase con ngClass como alerta visual, y vuelvo a regresar a su normalidad cuando se detecta el evento 'exit'.

HTML:

```
<div #DragAndDrop [class]="Class">
    <div class="Header" >Arrastra o Selecciona el Archivo</div>
    <div class="MyContent">
        <ion-icon name="document"></ion-icon>
    </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild('DragAndDrop', { static: false, }) DraggedFile: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

dragEnter$ = defer(() => fromEvent(this.DraggedFile.nativeElement, 
    'dragenter')).pipe( tap((event: any) => { this.Class = "Dragging" })
);

dragExit$ = defer(() => fromEvent(this.DraggedFile.nativeElement, 
    'dragleave')).pipe(
    tap((event: any) => { this.Class = "Drag" })
);
```

La funcionalidad del código no es importante, el problemna es que me detecta el arrastrar un archivo en el div Padre:

```
<div #DragAndDrop [class]="Class">
```

pero al pasar por uno de los elementos hijos se detona el evento exit y v cambia a la primer clase que tenia, quiero que mientras permanezca dentro del div, la clase no cambie
Alguien sabe como resolver esto?

En la siguiente imagen esta mi ejemplo, El div es el que tiene el borde, si arrastro un componente dentro de este div (en el fondo blanco) detecta que estoy arrastrandolo, pero al pasar por cualquier otro componente (los que tienen fondo Rojo,azul y negro), ahí se detona el evento exit

Como lo puedo evitar?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo pudiste resolver?

Comment: No amigo, tienes alguna idea o tienes el mismo problema?

Comment: La verdad no tengo ni una idea.